# Validate time against time interval

Tags: c#, timespan

I have three rules:

- A. Time slot between 9am and 3pm
- B. Time slot betweem 3pm and 7pm
- C. Time slot between 7pm and 9am

Currently I represented them as `TimeSpan`s

```
public class Rule
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public TimeSpan From {get; set;}
}

List<Rule> rules = new List<Rule>()
{
   new Rule() {From = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0), Name = "A"},
   new Rule() {From = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0), Name = "B"},
   new Rule() {From = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0), Name = "C"}
};
```

My question is how to validate the time input let's say 9.10pm against that rules?

It should pick third rule.

Comment: You have a problem in that, your time spans overlap. 9am is in both A and C, 3pm is in both A and B, and 7pm is in both B and C.

Comment: @Kevin presumably the start is inclusive and the end is exclusive.

Comment: Ok, I can add TimeSpan To, so  From = 9am and To=14.59pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight modification by adding an end time to the `Rule` object

```
public class Rule {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan From { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan To { get; set; }
}
```

this extension method was used to check if a provided input is within the time range of the rule.

```
public static class RuleExtension {
    public static bool Contains(this Rule rule, TimeSpan input) {
        var value = TimeSpan.Parse(input.ToString());
        var start = rule.From;
        var end = rule.To;

        if (end < start) {
            //loopback
            end += TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            if (value < start)
                value += TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        }

        return start.CompareTo(value) <= 0 && value.CompareTo(end) < 0;
    }
}
```

The following unit test was used to validate the extension method and extraxt a rule from a collection. *(Note: used FluentAssertions to assert results.)*

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void _ValidateTime() {
        var rules = new List<Rule>()
        {
           new Rule() {From = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0), To = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0), Name = "A"},
           new Rule() {From = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0), To = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0), Name = "B"},
           new Rule() {From = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0), To= new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0), Name = "C"}
        };

        var input = TimeSpan.Parse("21:10");
        rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Contains(input))
            .Should()
            .NotBeNull()
            .And
            .Match((Rule r) => r.Name == "C");

        input = TimeSpan.Parse("08:10");
        rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Contains(input))
            .Should()
            .BeNull();

        input = TimeSpan.Parse("18:10");
        rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Contains(input))
            .Should()
            .NotBeNull()
            .And
            .Match((Rule r) => r.Name == "B");

        input = TimeSpan.Parse("10:10");
        rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Contains(input))
            .Should()
            .NotBeNull()
            .And
            .Match((Rule r) => r.Name == "A");
    }
```

Comment: @Andrei here is my input to this topic

Comment: Good solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
DateTime input = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan span = input.TimeOfDay;
for (int i = 0; i < rules.Count - 1; i++) {
    if (span >= rules[i].From && span < rules[i + 1].From) {
        return rules[i];
    }
}
return rules[rules.Count - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below might do the trick:

```
var currentSpan = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.Date;
int ruleIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < rules.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (currentSpan >= rules[i].From && currentSpan < rules[i + 1].From)
    {
        ruleIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (ruleIndex == -1 && (currentSpan >= rules.Last().From || currentSpan < rules.First().From))
{
    ruleIndex = rules.Count - 1;
}

var rule = rules[ruleIndex];
```

Comment: If you want the current time you can just do `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`

Comment: @juharr, thanks, I have already noticed it in msitt's answer.

Comment: It fails if I input var current = new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0); OR var current = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0);

Comment: @Andrei, let me try to run it and see.

Comment: It does not cater to the switch over from midnight.

Comment: It works good for rule A and B but there is a problem with C as it is like from 19.00 to 7.00 and you cannot say that 20.00 > 7.00 if you know what I mean. Thanks for looking into that Andrii

Comment: I am glad it helped, msitt also provided good very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 24 hours in a day.  Could you just make a map array with an enum for assignments:

```
public enum Category
{
 A,
 B,
 C
}
```

Then the array.  So from your categories above 00:00 - 09:00 would be C.

```
Category[] values = new Category[24];
for(int i = 0;i<9;i++)
{
 values[i] = Category.C;
}
```

So you could assign each hour similarly.

Now given an hour (say 6am) as an input you can use a switch:

```
switch(values[6]) // gets the appropriate category.
{
  case Category.A:
   // handle
   break;
  case Category.B:
   // Handle
   break;
  case Category.C:
   // handle
   break;
  default:
   break;

}
```